# Pantheon Mail - Personal Folder

Tags: pantheon-mail, pantheon

Is it possible to create personal folders in the default mail tool on Pantheon-mail?
Is it possible to create a file (like .pst) to archive the messages and restore it if necessary?

Alexandre